Accessing a variable in a derived type that was allocated from a class of the parent type
I am trying to access a variable foo that I have declared in a derived type from a variable bar that was initially declared as CLASS(BaseType), ALLOCATABLE :: bar, and then allocated as ALLOCATE(Type1 :: bar). When I do so, I get the compilation error:
TEST.f90:16:12:

   16 |     bar%foo = 1
      |            1
Error: ‘foo’ at (1) is not a member of the ‘basetype’ structure

The test code that generates this error is:
MODULE test_mod
    TYPE BaseType
    END TYPE BaseType

    TYPE, EXTENDS(BaseType) :: DerivedType
        INTEGER :: foo
    END TYPE DerivedType

    CLASS(BaseType), ALLOCATABLE :: bar
END MODULE test_mod

PROGRAM TEST
    USE test_mod

    ALLOCATE(DerivedType :: bar)
    bar%foo = 1
    PRINT *, bar%foo

END PROGRAM TEST

I had expected that bar would become an instance of DerivedType after the ALLOCATE statement, but may not be understanding what exactly is happening during ALLOCATE? I tried to use SELECT TYPE to see if it is a DerivedType, and indeed bar is a DerivedType. I declared a DerivedType directly in PROGRAM TEST and could access its foo variable as well.

You know that you can use SELECT TYPE to be able to access the component, so the linked question is about why that is necessary. That question is about bindings rather than components but the same thing is relevant. In short: with a reference like a%b it's the declared type of a that's relevant,  not the dynamic type. ("Declared" and "dynamic" being the terms you want to search for to learn more.)
